# Cannot convert type to instance of interface in generic method with type constraint?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

Why does this give me a compile time error `Cannot convert 'ListCompetitions' to 'TOperation'`:

```
public class ListCompetitions : IOperation
{
}

public TOperation GetOperation<TOperation>() where TOperation : IOperation
{
    return (TOperation)new ListCompetitions(); 
}
```

Yet this is perfectly legal:

```
public TOperation GetOperation<TOperation>() where TOperation : IOperation
{
    return (TOperation)(IOperation)new ListCompetitions(); 
}
```

Comment: A Giraffe is a kind of animal. Gerry is a giraffe. In the next sentence, "T" can be replaced with any kind of animal. Gerry the giraffe is a T.  Now do you see the problem? The only valid values for T that make that sentence true are "giraffe" and "animal", but T can be *any* kind of animal.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that makes sense (though I would have thought it could still be a runtime error, rather than compiler error, though I'm sure there is a deeper reason why you guys implemented it that way that eludes me..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `TOperation` could be **anything** that implements `IOperation`, you can't be sure that `ListCompetitions` is a `TOperation`.

You probably want to be returning an IOperation:

```
public IOperation GetOperation<TOperation>() where TOperation : IOperation
{
    return new ListCompetitions(); 
}
```

Comment: In that case, what is the purpose the the generic parameter `TOperation`?

Comment: Svick - In the actual code TOperation will be a more specific version of IOperation and this will be a factory method that returns the correct concrete.

Answer (score 4):

This cast is not safe since you could supply a generic argument different from `ListCompetitions` for `TOperation`, for example you could have:

```
public class OtherOperation : IOperation { }
OtherOperation op = GetOperation<OtherOperation>();
```

If the compiler allowed your method, this would fail at runtime.

You could add a new constraint e.g.

```
public TOperation GetOperation<TOperation>() where TOperation : IOperation, new()
{
    return new TOperation();
}
```

alternatively you could change the return type to `IOperation`:

```
public IOperation GetOperation()
{
    return new ListCompetitions();
}
```

It's not clear what the benefit of using generics is in this case from your example.

Comment: You're casting to `TOperation`, not `IOperation`.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov - He's casting to `TOperation` not `IOperation`.

Comment: yeap, didn't catch immediately the difference in `I` and `T`, +1

Comment: Ignore the usage, this is a cut down example. Why not allow the runtime failure as with other casts? Why allow me to do this: ` (TOperation)(IOperation)new ListCompetitions();` ?

Comment: @MalcomTucker You can cast “up” and you can cast “down”, but you can't directly cast “sideways”.